# How to animate raster time series using open-source GIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, open-source-gis, animation, spatio-temporal-data

I have a bunch of rasters taken about 10 minutes apart, and I have a nice QGIS project that produces pretty enough maps of them. I'm wondering if there's a way to animate this raster series, with a color map and overlaid with (static) vector data, using open-source GIS. A QGIS solution would be ideal since I already have the project set up there, but other suggestions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 5):

See here how to easily make movies with raster data: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Movies

Comment: For the record: GRASS GIS 7 comes now with a full temporal GIS framework, see http://grass.osgeo.org/news/44/15/GRASS-GIS-7-0-1-RC1/ (animation: http://grass.osgeo.org/uploads/images/grass70_temporal_chlorophyll_anim_small.gif)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Time Manager](http://underdark.wordpress.com/projects/time-manager/) for QGIS. This [introduction](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/an-introduction-to-time-manager-for-qgis/) seems to indicate it will do what you want.

Comment: Time Manager doesn't support raster yet.

Comment: Oops - I missed that, I usually only have vectors.

Comment: There is a raster branch, but I haven't tested it yet: https://github.com/gvb/TimeManager/tree/raster

Comment: @underdark, the TM link was broken. I changed it to http://underdark.wordpress.com/tag/time-manager/, but dunno if that's the right place.